# Who did Captain Hook’s voice in Shrek Forever After?

Tags: shrek, actor-identification, shrek-forever-after

In *Shrek the Third*, Captain Hook redeems himself and says he grows daffodils. On the *Shrek Forever After* soundtrack, he talks to Rumpelstiltskin about his daffodil garden.

I know Tom Waits and Nick Cave played him in *Shrek 2*, Matt Mahaffey in *Shrek Far Far Away Idol* and Ian McShane in *Shrek the Third*, but who voiced him in *Shrek Forever After*?

Answer (score 1):

[AllMusic.com](https://www.allmusic.com/song/hooks-garrrrden-mt0036390953) lists the writers/composers/voices of the skit *Hook's Garrrrden* as Ryan Crego (Director), Walt Dohrn (the voice of Rumpel) and Gina Shay (Dreamworks Producer)

It would appear that **Dohrn is doing both voices**, something that's most noticeable when he shifts from one character to the other and basically forgets to do the accent.

Note that the voice actor for Shrek 3 (Ian McShane) is **[also credited as Hook in Shrek Forever](https://voiceactors.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/shrek-forever-after/)** but it isn't his voice on the soundtrack.